# apply() not working, retuns numeric(0)

Tags: r, apply

I wrote a very simple function that should take a vector of data, do a few computations, and return a single value. The function works as expected if I extract rows from a data frame and run it on each row (e.g., function(x[1,]); however, when I try to run it on an entire date frame, it returns "numeric(0)". I am at my wits end because I know that the function works when used one row at a time, and I use apply() all the time, so I have no clue why it won't work. The function is below ("Hexp") as well as some example data ("data") and the line of code that I am trying to use to execute it. Thanks for the help

```
Hexp <- function(x){
  hom1 <- sum(x==10)
  hom2 <- sum(x==1)
  het <- sum(x==11)
  miss2 <- sum(x=="--")
  a1 <- (hom1*2+het)/((ncol(x)-miss2)*2)
  a2 <- (hom2*2+het)/((ncol(x)-miss2)*2)
  h <- 2*a1*a2}

data <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,11,10),c(1,"--",10)))
result <- apply(data,1,Hexp)
```

Comment: You need to make the function return something, e.g. add another line `h`. Right now it just assigns a bunch of local variables which get deleted as soon as it's finished running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually tried that before posting (sorry, I should have mentioned that), and the result is the same

Comment: Oh, you need to use `length` instead of `ncol`, because `apply` is breaking it up into a vector for each row.

Comment: Brilliant, that does it. Thanks!